# difference of add sql file and sql project in visual studio

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, three-tier

I have an huge web project with 3 layer (UI,business logic, data access layer). I need to add sql database to it.
There are two ways to do it:

1- Add Database Project like this:

[image]

2- Add sql database like this:

[image]

Which way is better?

Thanks.

Comment: why not make a test ? The one must be a connection to the database, the other must be a connection direct to the database file... (both is actually the same, but the one see the file, the other see the database)

Comment: @Aristos I've already tested both methods. Both working properly but I don't know which way is better?

Comment: There is no better - they are the same database behind.

Comment: @Aristos Which are usually used in large-scale projects?

Comment: the SQL Server Database Project